# Removing a specific pinned/starred message from a chat room

Tags: support, chat, chat-stars

Is there any way to remove the stars/pins from a starred/pinned message?

There should be some kind of way to remove them, and room owners should have that capability.

Comment: Oh...wait.. are you asking about removing **all** starred/pinned messages or only one? Your title doesn't really match the body of your question...

Comment: @Lix I have updated title of my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a room owner, clicking on the little black arrow in the bottom right corner of a pinned/starred message will bring up a little popup.

[image]

Clicking on the "cancel stars" link will remove all stars from that message and will also unpin the message.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation

Comment: @Aღmirkhan - Glad to help :) Happy chatting!